# Combine -vf yadif,format=yuv420p and -filter_complex for watermark

Tags: ffmpeg, filter

I have an ffmpeg command using -vf to deinterlace videos and produce pixel format with 4:2:0 chroma subsampling:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf yadif,format=yuv420p \ 
-force_key_frames expr:gte(t\,n_forced/2) \
-c:v libx264 -crf 23 output.mp4
```

Also I have another ffmpeg command to put on my watermark:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -i logo.png \
-filter_complex "[1][0]scale2ref=iw/5:ow*450/450[wm][vid];[vid][wm]overlay=W-w-W*3/100:H-h-H*1/100:enable='gt(t,30)'" \
-c:v libx264 -crf 23 output.mp4
```

I tried to put them together and got this error:

```
-vf/-af/-filter and -filter_complex cannot be used together for the same stream
```

I read that -filter_complex can be used for simple filters, and we can chain the filters together, separated by commas, so I created a new command without -vf:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -i logo.png \
filter_complex "[1][0]scale2ref=iw/5:ow*450/450[wm][vid];[vid][wm]overlay=W-w-W*3/100:H-h-H*1/100:enable='gt(t,30)',yadif,format=yuv420p" -force_key_frames expr:gte(t\,n_forced/2) -c:v libx264 -crf 23 output.mp4
```

Is this the right way to combine these two filters?

The console doesn't show the above error but a new error:

```
Missing ')' or too many args in 'gte(t\,n_forced/2)'
Invalid force_key_frames expression 'gte(t\,n_forced/2)'
Error initializing output stream 0:0 --
[aac @ 0000022fbe6eacc0] Qavg: 118.000
[aac @ 0000022fbe6eacc0] 2 frames left in the queue on closing
Conversion failed!
```

Please help!

Comment: The working answer has been posted below!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -i logo.png \
-filter_complex "[0]yadif,format=yuv420p[main];[1][main]scale2ref=iw/5:ow*450/450[wm][vid];[vid][wm]overlay=W-w-W*3/100:H-h-H*1/100:enable='gt(t,30)'" \
-force_key_frames "expr:gte(t,n_forced/2)" -c:v libx264 -crf 23 -c:a copy output.mp4
```